# jQuery: How to attach submit event in Firefox and Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery

I have the following handler in my page that works fine in Firefox, but apparently is not being attached in IE8, since it adds the parameters to the URL, and does not make any ajax calls the server:

```
$('#editBox form').live('submit',function(event){
        var daId = $('#editBox #id').val();

        $.post(
            '/edit.php',
            {
                company: $('#company',this).val(),
                name: $('#name',this).val(),
                email: $('#email',this).val(),
                id: daId 
            },
            function(response){
                sel = 'tr#' + daId;
                $(sel).html(response)
                .animate({backgroundColor: 'yellow'},500)
                .animate({backgroundColor: 'white'},500);

                $(sel + ' td:nth-child(3)').addClass('lastCell');

            });

            $('#editBox').hide('fast', function(){
                toggleHider();
                $(this).remove();
            });

            updateSorting();                

            consoleMessage('User changes saved');

        return false;
});
```

How can I make this work in both IE and FF?

**Update**

I'm still not able to get this working right.  Using Joel's solution below, here's what I have:

```
function BindSubmit()
{
    $('#editBox form').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
            var daId = $('#editBox #id').val();

            $.post(
                '/webadmin/CDAdmin/editrep.php',
                {
                    company: $('#company',this).val(),
                    name: $('#name',this).val(),
                    email: $('#email',this).val(),
                    id: daId 
                },
                function(response){
                    sel = 'tr#' + daId;
                    $(sel).html(response)
                    .animate({backgroundColor: 'yellow'},500)
                    .animate({backgroundColor: 'white'},500);

                    $(sel + ' td:nth-child(3)').addClass('lastCell');

                });

                $('#editBox').hide('fast', function(){
                    toggleHider();
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                updateSorting();                

                consoleMessage('User changes saved');

            return false;
    });
}
```

And here's how I'm trying to use it:

```
$tr.live('click',function(event){
        if ( $('#editBox').length ){
            $('#editBox').remove();
        }   

        var eb = $('<div>').attr('id','editBox');

        $('#startEditBox').children().clone(true).appendTo(eb);

        BindSubmit();
```

But it doesn't work.  Now, the event isn't attached in either FF or IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`live()` is not supported on the submit event in JQuery 1.3.x. Try the [JQuery 1.4 RC 1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4rc1.js).

If upgrading is not an option, you will have to manually bind the submit event every time you add a form to the page.

E.g.

```
function BindSubmit()
{
    $('#editBox form').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
        ...
    });
}
```

Then call `BindSubmit()` every time you add a form element to `#editBox`.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.4 RC 1 did not seem to make a difference - still doesn't work in IE

Comment: Hmm, I haven't actually used 1.4 yet, but the docs say it supports all js events. Anyway, see my edit for a method to directly bind the event any time a form is added.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm still having trouble.  Please see my update to the original question.

Comment: You need to add the editBox to the DOM before you call `BindSubmit()`. See mr. moses' last update.

Answer (score 2):

`submit` is not supported as a live event

from http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn

> Currently not supported: blur, focus, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit

and

> .live (currently) supports a subset of all events. Note the full list of supported/not-supported events above.

I had the same issue with `$.live("change")` It worked in FF, but not IE.  I ended up using $.change().

I suggest using $.submit()

Bind the event whenever a new `form` is added to `#editBox`

```
$('#editBox form').submit(function(event){
  ..
});
```

**Update**

Make sure you add the editBox element to the Dom before trying to bind the submit event.

```
$tr.live('click',function(event){
  if ( $('#editBox').length ){
    $('#editBox').remove();
  }   

  var eb = $('<div>').attr('id','editBox');

  $('#startEditBox').children().clone(true).appendTo(eb);

  //add into the page somewhere
  $('#something').append(eb);

  //then bind the submit event
  BindSubmit();
```

Comment: @Jacob: FF's event model is not the same as IE's. I'm guessing that submit events bubble in FF but not IE, hence delegation to a parent element does not work.

Comment: @croceldon: Up-voting the answers that were helpful is a way to give back to the community.